How do I close down modal stack in MAUI app (with Prism)
We have an existing Xamrin Forms app that we are migrating to MAUI. At the same time we are switching to Prism.
One of the navigation appraches we have is during the setup and use of Bluetooth devices we run the user through a series of Modal pages. At the end of that flow we need to pop those modal pages and return to the uer from where they came.

Are we doing something very wrong by taking people through a series of modal pages? I ask this because it seems far too hard to close down a modal stack if this is normal behavior
If it is OK then how does one do it with Prism in MAUI because I have tried all differnt Navigation methods and none of them work for me.

I have raised this issue on the Github repro for Prism if you want to read more about the scenario. Exiting a stack of Modals and tidying them up and Add support for Relative Navigation '../' within a Modal Stack
